# How do we tag questions about Call Of Duty Zombies mode?

Tags: discussion, tags, sub-tags

There are [a lot of posts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=cod+zombies) about Call Of Duty's series-spanning game mode Zombies, but none of these questions have a tag that reflects the game mode itself.

In first page of the search I saw posts tagged [call-of-duty-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-series), [call-of-duty-world-at-war](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-world-at-war), [call-of-duty-advanced-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-advanced-warfare), [call-of-duty-infinite-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-infinite-warfare), [call-of-duty-ww2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-ww2), [call-of-duty-black-ops](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops), [call-of-duty-black-ops-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops-2) for questions that were all related to the Zombies mode.

Each of these games have their own Zombies game mode, but should they also have a specific tag for it? The game mode has taken on a life of its own, having appeared in at least nine games since its inception in Call of Duty: World at War.

Additionally, these tags do not encompass questions that are not game-specific such as how to download custom maps or questions about [game strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/262068/why-do-you-have-to-open-doors-in-cod-zombies) or Zombies mode, lore which is distinct from the Call of Duty Series lore.

I do not believe these tags cannot be made game specific because of an iOS game [Call of Duty: Black Ops Zombies](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies/id471063940) which would obfuscate questions. How would we tag Call of Duty Black Ops Zombies (2010) with Call of Duty Black Ops Zombies (2011) iOS without changing the naming convention of every other Call of Duty tag?

Right now, I feel such questions do not fit within the [call-of-duty-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-series) where they're frequently posted. Adding such a tag would make it easier to search for these kinds of questions. Much in the same way we have tags for [grand-theft-auto-v](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-v) and [grand-theft-auto-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-online) where the game is drastically different.

I would like to propose a [call-of-duty-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-zombies) tag to encompass this game mode. Any thoughts?

Comment: There is precedent for a) individual subtags (i.e. one per game), b) cross-game subtags ([tag:starcraft-terran] being used for both Starcraft 1 and 2 etc) and c) series-level tags (like [call-of-duty-series]). Personally, for alternate game modes under multiple games, I'd prefer (a), as it doesn't muddy the tag with strategy/tactics/map-specific questions that may or may not apply to every game.

Comment: Post this comment as an answer so I can accept it. You have valid points, especially about map-specific questions. Too bad tags can be so limiting, CoD zombies is basically it's own franchise now.

Comment: Let's not forget that we have 35 symbols limit for tags, so even [call-of-duty-infinite-warfare-zombies] (38) won't fit

Comment: @arghtype - there's no reason sub-tags can't be abbreviated, like how the Team Fortress 2 subtags are abbreviated to tf2 eg [tag:tf2-medic], [tag:tf2-mann-vs-machine] etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a couple of options, as this is handled differently between various games and series. There is precedent for:

- Individual subtags i.e. subtags per game
- Cross-game subtags - For example, [starcraft-terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-terran) being used for both [starcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft) and [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2)
- Series level tags - like [call-of-duty-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-series), meant for questions about the series as a whole.

In this case, I'd personally prefer individual subtags for each game. While the 'zombies' game mode shares similarities in some aspects cross-game, in others it can vary: gameplay, controls, strategy, available pickups/perks, weapons (including their stats),  and maps all change between games, just like the base gameplay of the Call of Duty series.

It would make sense to keep them separate.

---

#### What should we name them?

Given our 35-character limitation for tag names, the full game name + 'zombies' is a bit too long in some cases. Instead, we could abbreviate the 'Call-of-Duty' part of the name:

- [call-of-duty-world-at-war](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-world-at-war) -> [cod-world-at-war-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cod-world-at-war-zombies)
- [call-of-duty-advanced-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-advanced-warfare) -> [cod-advanced-warfare-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cod-advanced-warfare-zombies)
- [call-of-duty-infinite-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-infinite-warfare) -> [cod-infinite-warfare-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cod-infinite-warfare-zombies)
- [call-of-duty-ww2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-ww2) -> [cod-ww2-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cod-ww2-zombies)
- [call-of-duty-black-ops](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops) -> [cod-black-ops-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cod-black-ops-zombies)
- [call-of-duty-black-ops-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops-2) -> [cod-black-ops-2-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cod-black-ops-2-zombies)

To avoid a clash with the iOS game, we could rename that tag to the following:

- [call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies) -> [call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies-ios](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies-ios)

Comment: What would happen when the iOS game is release for multiple platforms? There's quite a risk to adding a platform to a tag name.

Comment: @Robotnik Is this something I can go ahead and do, or is there some sort of process I'd need to wait for?

Comment: @Mast You're right - it was released for Android too, my bad. How about `[cod-black-ops-zombies-mobile]`?

Comment: @PausePause - Go ahead. We will have to manually edit the tag onto relevant questions over time (probably 5-10 at a time so we don't flood the front page).

Comment: Better, although there's still a risk somebody decides to port that game to Steam like has been done with enough mobile games.

Comment: @Robotnik I'll get started. There are quite a few so it might take a couple of days

Comment: @Mast - Let's cross that bridge if/when it comes up. The game is 8 years old at this point, was last updated in 2016, and (at least on Android) has a message saying EU countries can no longer play it, so it's heading towards EOL. I can't see a Steam release in the near future.