# Renaming [call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies] to [cod-black-ops-zombies-mobile]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

From a [recent discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14635/how-do-we-tag-questions-about-call-of-duty-zombies-mode?cb=1) the decision has been made to expand questions about Call of Duty Zombies mode to include tags specific to the game's zombies mode.

For instance, a question about the game mode in [call-of-duty-advanced-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-advanced-warfare) would be expanded to have an additional tag of [cod-advanced-warfare-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cod-advanced-warfare-zombies).

This leaves the obscure mobile game Call of Duty Black Ops Zombies (2011) in an uncomfortable place. After all, the tag has an explicit conflict with the Call of Duty Black Ops (2010) game mode of the same name. The crossover is problematic enough the [call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies) tag [has a description explicitly prohibiting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies) questions about the 2010 game mode.

> "a 2011 zombie survival game for iOS and a spin-off of the game mode from main-series Call of Duty games. Do not use for zombie-modes in other CoD games, use the relevant game's tag instead."

With the adoption of Zombies-mode-specific tags this [call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies) needs to be renamed to [cod-black-ops-zombies-mobile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cod-black-ops-zombies-mobile).

This change shortens "Call-of-Duty" to "cod" to conform to the 35 character tag length limit. [call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies-mobile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies-mobile) is two characters too long. Additionally, the word "mobile" would be appended to the end to encompass both Android and iOS releases.

The renaming of this tag would allow other Zombies mode tags to exist without risk of overlap of topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rename is now done:

- [call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies) -> [cod-black-ops-zombies-mobile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cod-black-ops-zombies-mobile)

I did not leave the synonym in place, so that [call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies) can be used for the Zombies game mode as discussed.